# How do you get a cross section of data from a Pandas dataframe with a key for a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this

```
A, B, C
d, 1, 2
d, 3, 4
e, 5, 6
e, 7, 8
```

I am trying to get

```
B, C
1, 2
3, 4
```

and

```
B, C
5, 6
7, 8
```

By iterating through d, e, etc.

I can get the keys just fine looping though `df.index.levels[0]`

I can not figure out how to get a cross section of the data though. I have tried this

```
df.xs(key=df.index.levels[0][0], level=df.index.levels[0])
```

but I get this error

> {ValueError}The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I have no clue what a is, but this does not work

```
df.xs(key=df.index.levels[0][0], level=df.index.levels[0]).all()
```

Same error message.

The docs make it sound like xs should work like that, so I am at a loss.

Comment: This doesn't look like a multiindex. Is your dataframe initially nonMultiIndex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.loc to get your desired output.

```
for i in df['A'].unique():
    print(df.loc[df['A'] == i][['B','C']])

   B  C
0  1  2
1  3  4

   B  C
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Comment: ```df.loc[df['A'] == i]``` is close to what I ended up with which was ```df.loc['d']```

Comment: `df.loc['d']` will work if you have set your column A to index. My answer is for non index column A :D

Answer (score 0):

In your case just do

```
for x, y in df.groupby('A'):
    print(y)
```